# How to call malloc in x86_64 asm

Tags: assembly, malloc, x86-64, masm, msvcrt

I am trying to call malloc in Visual Studio Community 2019 assembly but I keep getting undefined reference to symbol malloc.

```
mov rcx,10h
call malloc
```

Does not compile as I get the undefined reference to malloc
I have even tried it with _malloc with the same issue.
Am I missing some sort of include?

Comment: This would be a better question if you quoted the *exact* error message, so it was clear it was from the assembler, not at link time.  (If you declared `extern malloc` but then didn't link with the C library, you'd expect some kind of undefined reference when linking, after assembling successfully.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by putting an extern in the data section

```
.data
extern malloc: proc
.code 
;Some code;
```

Comment: If this actually solved your problem you should accept your answer!

Comment: I have to wait 2 days

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I forgot the wait time was so long. Never mind.

Comment: Are you sure the `extern malloc: proc` has to be in `.data`?  That seems odd, unless that creates a placeholder for dynamic linking (a pointer for indirect call) at the position you declare it.  I don't use MASM, but in other assemblers for other OSes, e.g. NASM, `extern malloc` could be anywhere and is just a directive that has no interaction with the current section.